# Get the calculation of random numbers to compare with an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Recently I have been trying how to get the calculation of two random numbers that are shown in MainActivity to compare later with the text field and indicate if the number inserted is correct or no.

Here the code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.miguel.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNum = random.nextInt(101);
    int randomNum2 = random.nextInt(101);
    String messageRandomNum = String.valueOf(randomNum);
    String messageRandomNum2 = String.valueOf(randomNum2);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textViewRandomNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.random_num);
    textViewRandomNum.setText(messageRandomNum);
    messageRandomNum2 = String.valueOf(randomNum2+ "= ");
    TextView textViewRandomNum2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.random_num2);
    textViewRandomNum2.setText(messageRandomNum2);

}

public int getCalculation(){
    //Here is where I had tried to get the calculation of the same numbers that are shown in the screen
    int calculation = randomNum + randomNum2;
    return calculation;
}

public void sendMessage (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
package com.example.miguel.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        int messageInt = Integer.parseInt(message);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);

        //The comparison of editText and the calculation
        if(messageInt == mainActivity.getCalculation()){
            textView.setText("Correct!");
        }else{
            textView.setText("Incorrect!");
        }

        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message);
        layout.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

Always is shown that the inserted number (although it is well) shows "Incorrect!". I don't know why the calculation does a sum of random numbers, but not the random numbers than are shown in the screen.

If you don't understand something, sorry, I'm a Spanish speaker.

Regards! ;)

Comment: you should sent calculation using intent too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MainActivity you can send calculated result

```
public void sendMessage (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        int calcualtedResult=getCalculation();
         intent.putInt("calcualtedResult", calcualtedResult);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

In DisplayMessageActivity

you can get the intent

```
           int calculatedRes=intent.getInt("calculatedResult");


            if(messageInt == calculatedRes){
                textView.setText("Correct!");
            }else{
                textView.setText("Incorrect!");
            }
```

Comment: you can not do MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity(); for accessing method of main activity.

Comment: The concept is good, but the code It doesn't have to be this way, because Android Studio says that is wrong. Anyway I have corrected it and now works. Thank you for the attention ;D

Answer (score 0):

wrong thing in your code is that you create an object from MainActivity in your DisplayMessageActivity. this object differ from activity that call DisplayMessageActivity and hasn't your random numbers. you must send random numbers with intent to next Activity, like EXTRA_MESSAGE.